# Edit VMX file with vSphere Client

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual, esxi

i'm looking for a correct solution to editing VMX file via vSphere clinet without need to SSH to ESX host or using VI and Nano
could anybody please help me??

Answer (score 1):

@Hwoosuk The best way , those i have to use with Vmware, is to get Winscp http://winscp.net and connect it directly to the esxi IP console after enable SSH in the Vmware Firewall (configure/soft/security profile)  , you can browse all the local esxi Disk or VMFS on you SAN/NAS. Edit Whatever you want **carefully** , your log etc.., your Vmxf (no write or edit permit by vmware if the VM is power on).So this is the best way to go inside the vmware file system for reading the low-level subsystem. Enjoy Winscp for any linux serveur you may use in your life with an micro$ computer you may use for admin your datacenter. In the winscp menu go to options/pref and paste the directory where you have Putty installed.`(%PROGRAMFILES%\PuTTY\putty.exe)`. Retain @mister_potato_head solution to do it safely as vmware imposes it , in most case this is the better thing you have to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

The VMX file is generated by vSphere,  it you add a new NIC using GUI the vmx file will get updated to reflect this.  With this in mind you can use any method to issue commands to edit VM configuration and therefore the vmx file.

Alternately if you would like to edit the VMX file directly you can use PowerCLI as described [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/468449)